# Does the Nginx default block suffice?

Tags: 8

The following conf file is my default Nginx conf (it's basically the one shipped with Nginx 1.10.3 in Ubuntu).

```
server {
    # listen, root, index, server_name, locations;
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;
    root /var/www/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
    server_name _;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

This is my individual app Nginx configuration.

```
server {
    root ${drt}/${domain}/;
    server_name ${domain} www.${domain};
    location ~* \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|ico|css|js|ttf|woff|pdf)$ { expires 365d; }
}
```

Are these Nginx configuration files enough for basic, all-default Drupal usage (i.e. all core, no module customization, and up to 5 typical third-party modules)?

Enough in the sense of getting Drupal 8.4.x or later to work, with basic security.

Comment: A quick google search pointed me to https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/drupal/.

Comment: This is what I used last year. Should be still valid. I toke me a lot of time to put it together. https://gist.github.com/ivanjaros/14837fd3d34ffce3fb50acc62724e8ab although it was for cloud environment(kubernetes pod).

Comment: @Berdir I already bumped in this. I am far from being an Nginx expert as to say why is it significantly longer then my example here.

Comment: @IvanJaros why does it have to be so long in Drupal? :\

Comment: Maybe one of you two want to publish his answer?

Comment: I now give 200 bounty.

Answer (score 0):

Here's our stock nginx config include file for Drupal sites.  It gets modified to match any special file locations or other requirements and included at the bottom of the server section.

```
### Nginx configuration for Drupal. This configuration makes use of
### drush (http:///drupal.org/project/drush) for site maintenance
### and like tasks:
###
### 1. Run the cronjobs.
### 2. Run the DB and code updates: drush up or drush upc followed by
###    drush updb to run any DB updates required by the code upgrades
###    that were performed.
### 3. Disabling of xmlrpc.xml, install.php (needed only for
###    installing the site) and update.php: all updates are now
###    handled through drush.

## To avoid the ugly rewrite we use Lua to escape the URI.
set_by_lua $escaped_uri 'return ngx.escape_uri(ngx.var.uri)';

## The 'default' location.
location / {
  ## Drupal 404 from can impact performance. If using a module like
  ## search404 then 404's *have *to be handled by Drupal. Uncomment to
  ## relay the handling of 404's to Drupal.
  ## error_page 404 /index.php;

  ## Using a nested location is the 'correct' way to use regexes.

  ## Regular private file serving (i.e. handled by Drupal).
  location ^~ /system/files/ {
    ## Include the specific FastCGI configuration. This is for a
    ## FCGI backend like php-cgi or php-fpm.
    include conf/drupal/fastcgi_drupal8.conf;
    fastcgi_pass phpcgi;

    ## For not signaling a 404 in the error log whenever the
    ## system/files directory is accessed add the line below.
    ## Note that the 404 is the intended behavior.
    log_not_found off;
  }

  ## Trying to access private files directly returns a 404.
  location ^~ /sites/*/files/private/ {
    internal;
  }

  ## Support for the file_force module
  ## http://drupal.org/project/file_force.
  location ^~ /system/files_force/ {
    ## Include the specific FastCGI configuration. This is for a
    ## FCGI backend like php-cgi or php-fpm.
    include conf/drupal/fastcgi_drupal8.conf;
    fastcgi_pass phpcgi;

    ## For not signaling a 404 in the error log whenever the
    ## system/files directory is accessed add the line below.
    ## Note that the 404 is the intended behavior.
    log_not_found off;
  }

  ## If accessing an image generated by Drupal 6 imagecache, serve it
  ## directly if available, if not relay the request to Drupal to (re)generate
  ## the image.
  location ~* /imagecache/ {    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    try_files $uri @drupal;
  }

  ## Drupal 7 generated image handling, i.e., imagecache in core. See:
  ## http://drupal.org/node/371374.
  location ~* /files/styles/ {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    try_files $uri @drupal;
  }

  location ~* files/advagg_(?:css|js)/ {
    access_log  off;
    gzip_static on;
    access_log  off;
    expires     max;
    add_header  ETag '';
    add_header  Cache-Control 'max-age=31449600, no-transform, public';
    try_files $uri @drupal;
  }

  ## All static files will be served directly.
  location ~* ^.+\.(?:css|cur|js|jpe?g|gif|htc|ico|png|html?|xml|svg)$ {
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
    ## fell swoop.
    tcp_nodelay off;
    ## Set the OS file cache.
    open_file_cache max=3000 inactive=120s;
    open_file_cache_valid 45s;
    open_file_cache_min_uses 2;
    open_file_cache_errors off;
  }

  include conf/other/cross-domain-fonts.conf;

  ## PDFs and powerpoint files handling.
  location ~* ^.+\.(?:pdf|pptx?)$ {
    expires 30d;
    ## No need to bleed constant updates. Send the all shebang in one
    ## fell swoop.
    tcp_nodelay off;
  }

  ## MP3 and Ogg/Vorbis files are served using AIO when supported. Your OS must support it.
  location ~* ^/sites/*/files/.*\.(?:mp3|ogg)$ {
    directio 512; # for ext3 or similar (block alignments)
    tcp_nopush off;
    aio on;
    output_buffers 1 2M;
  }

        ## Pseudo streaming of H264/AAC files.
        ## Cf. http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_mp4_module.html.
  location ~* ^/sites/*/files/.*\.(?:mp4|mov|m4a)$ {
    mp4;
    mp4_buffer_size 1M;
    mp4_max_buffer_size 5M;
  }

  ## Advanced Help module makes each module provided README available.
  location ^~ /help/ {
    location ~* ^/help/[^/]*/README\.txt$ {
      ## Include the specific FastCGI configuration. This is for a
      ## FCGI backend like php-cgi or php-fpm.
      include conf/drupal/fastcgi_drupal8.conf;
      fastcgi_pass phpcgi;
    }
  }

  ## Replicate the Apache <FilesMatch> directive of Drupal standard
  ## .htaccess. Disable access to any code files. Return a 404 to curtail
  ## information disclosure. Hide also the text files.
  location ~* ^(?:.+\.(?:htaccess|make|txt|engine|inc|info|install|module|profile|po|pot|sh|.*sql|test|theme|tpl(?:\.php)?|xtmpl)|code-style\.pl|/Entries.*|/Repository|/Root|/Tag|/Template)$ {
    return 404;
  }

  ## First we try the URI and relay to the /index.php?q=$uri&$args if not found.
  try_files $uri @drupal;
}

########### Security measures ##########

## Restrict access to the strictly necessary PHP files. Reducing the
## scope for exploits. Handling of PHP code and the Drupal event loop.
location @drupal {
  ## Include the FastCGI config.
  include conf/drupal/fastcgi_drupal8.conf;
  fastcgi_pass phpcgi;

  track_uploads proxied 60s;
}

location @drupal-no-args {
  ## Include the specific FastCGI configuration. This is for a
  ## FCGI backend like php-cgi or php-fpm.
  include conf/drupal/fastcgi_no_args_drupal8.conf;
  fastcgi_pass phpcgi;

}

include conf/other/protect-system-files.conf;

## Disable access logs for robots.txt.
location = /robots.txt {
  access_log off;
  ## Add support for the robotstxt module
  ## http://drupal.org/project/robotstxt.
  try_files $uri @drupal-no-args;
}

## RSS feed support.
location = /rss.xml {
  try_files $uri @drupal-no-args;
}

## XML Sitemap support.
location = /sitemap.xml {
  try_files $uri @drupal-no-args;
}

## Support for favicon. Return an 1x1 transparent GIF if it doesn't
## exist.
location = /favicon.ico {
  expires 30d;
  try_files /favicon.ico @empty;
}

## Return an in memory 1x1 transparent GIF.
location @empty {
  expires 30d;
  empty_gif;
}

## Any other attempt to access PHP files returns a 404.
location ~* ^.+\.php$ {
  return 404;
}
```